# SQLite aggregate refer to calling SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, aggregate

I have a table, such as:

| TimeValue | Low |
| --- | --- |
| 14:00 | 123 |
| 14:30 | 012 |
| 15:00 | 456 |
| 15:30 | 145 |
| 16:00 | 678 |

I want to return the minimum "Low" that occurs on or after each TimeValue, so expected results would be:

| TimeValue | Min(Low) |
| --- | --- |
| 14:00 | 012 |
| 14:30 | 012 |
| 15:00 | 145 |
| 15:30 | 145 |
| 16:00 | 678 |

Have tried:

```
SELECT
    TimeValue AS thistime,
    (SELECT
        MIN(Low)
    FROM MyTable
    AND TimeValue >= thistime)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY thistime
;
```

but obviously SQLite doesn't recognize thistime from the inner SELECT statement.  How do we do this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `MIN` aggregation function, you can use the corresponding homonimous [window function](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html), which will return the minimum value for each row and for each partition. In order to group on the hour, you can use the [`STRFTIME`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) function as follows:

```
SELECT TimeValue,
       MIN(Low) OVER(PARTITION BY STRFTIME('%H', TimeValue))
FROM tab
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7h7s7RMZjc2nyfAEEixD53/0).

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out:

```
SELECT
    a.TimeValue,
    (SELECT MIN(Low) FROM MyTable WHERE TimeValue >= a.TimeValue) AS MyResult
FROM MyTable a;
```